# Eureka Dynamically Hide/Show Rows

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, eureka-forms

I have a option field that I created using Eureka. I want to create new fields according of the answer of my first option and show new row accordingly.

```
form +++ Section("First Section")
        <<< ActionSheetRow<String>() {
            $0.title = "Select Option"
            $0.selectorTitle = "1 or 2"
            $0.options = ["1","2"]
    }
```

For example, if I want to show new row according to the answer of the first question; so different form field row for 1 and 2, which was initially hidden. How can it be achieved?

So I want the flow to be: If 1 selected, show second question which is option select as well. If 2 selected show option with different set of options. But don't show that row before first option value is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I had been working in your questions, this are my results, you need to setup a tag for your section and then search in the form with tag get the section and add another cell according your needs, this code can help you

```
 <<< ActionSheetRow<String>() {
                $0.title = "Select Option"
                $0.selectorTitle = "1 or 2"
                $0.options = ["1","2"]
                $0.onChange({ (row) in
                    debugPrint("\(row.value) was selected")

                    if let section = self.form.sectionBy(tag: "first") {

                        let actionSheetRow = ActionSheetRow<String>()
                        actionSheetRow.title = "Select Option2"
                        actionSheetRow.title = "2 or 3"
                        actionSheetRow.options = ["2","3"]
                        actionSheetRow.onChange({ (row2) in
                            debugPrint("\(row2.value) was selected")
                        })
                        section.append(actionSheetRow)
                        section.reload(with: .none)
                    }

                })
            }
```

I hope this helps you, best regards

Comment: @senty did you try my answer?